# Send email using microsoft exchange server

Tags: java, email

I am trying to send an email from a microsoft exchange server and i cant seem to make it work.

This is my code:

```
private static void sendEmail(){
  host = "mail.tzr-019.co.il";
  Properties props = System.getProperties();
  props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", host);
  props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
  props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

  try{
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress,user));
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(TO));
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
     message.setText("This is actual message");
     Transport.send(message);

     System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
  }catch (Exception mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I get the error message:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't show us where you set `host`; would you please include that code?

Comment: Sorry, it's late and I missed it. What's the IP address for `mail.tzr-019.co.il` from where you are, and what happens with `telnet mail.tzr-019.co.il 25`?

Comment: It works now , i had some premmisions issue. ty

Answer (score 0):

As I see that you are trying to connect to localhost, I will assume that this is correct and you are the Exchange Server administrator and point to other possibilities.

Microsoft Exchange server uses by default a proprietary protocol called Exchange Active Sync. This is the most common set-up for corporate accounts, and (for example, in my case) other options may not be allowed. Each account may have a different privilege on using another protocols as for instance POP3 or IMAP4 and the send counterpart - SMTP.

Make sure that the account through you are trying to send the message is supporting the POP3 / IMAP4 synchronization.

See: [http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/cc875899(d=loband).aspx](http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/cc875899%28d=loband%29.aspx)